# Insert a colon in a chemical compound using mhchem or any other chem package available in MikTeX

Tags: equations, mhchem

New to LaTeX. I have only been using it for two weeks. I checked if this question was asked before. Can't find anything. I want to add a colon between the Al and NH3. At the moment all I can think of is the ugly hack shown below. Is there a better way of doing this which does not result in the space either side of the colon?
Many thanks..

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
      \ce{(CH3)_{6}Al2_{(g)} + 2NH3_{(g)} -> 2(CH3)_{3}Al}:\ce{ NH3_{(s)}} 
    \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

[image: Chemical reaction - output so far]

**EDIT**:I just found out about \colon but is still adds a space after the colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `mhchem`, you can escape text which you want to include literally by enclosing it in curly braces:

```
\ce{(CH3)6Al2_{(g)} + 2NH3_{(g)} -> 2(CH3)3Al{:}NH3_{(s)}}
```

I've also taken the liberty of of removing underscores where they aren't necessary: that's what you're using `mhchem` for, after all.

Comment: As always: If you can show to the author of the package that the colon notation is an official notation or very common (by citing an UIPAC or ACS document, for instance), then this will be officially supported (I think, in this instance, he would remove the need to use curly braces).